# What Is The Purpose Behind Different Icon Of System.Property?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Please be noted the Icon  of below Control’s Property

```
button1.Text
```

And be noted

```
FontStyle.Bold
```

The icon of Bold Property of enum Fontstyle is difer from above control’s Text property. Why?.
What you think about diference of icon of property?. What is the reason behind utilise the difere icon in system Property in above two case?.

Is it not misguid user to utilise it as a property?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two are very different things. `button1.Text` is a read-write instance property. On the other side, `FontStyle` is an `enum`. `FontStyle.Bold` is an `enum` item - a constant read-only value.

Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462439/meaning-of-visual-studio-intellisense-icons) for a meaning of other icons. One of the answers points to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @Miroslave Popovic, So as per yours answer FontSytle.Bold is a enum item only?.

Comment: @mahesh no, not a property; an enum value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontstyle.aspx

Comment: @mahesh yep, as Marc said, it's not a property

Comment: Ok @MarcGravell,Miroslav Popovic, What you want to say about this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.bold.aspx

Comment: @mahesh `Font` is a class, not an `enum`. `Font.Bold` is a read-only boolean property.

Comment: @mahesh what about it? Font is a class; Font.Bold is a property. FontStyle is an enum; FontStyle.Bold is an enum value (essentially a literal field). Your point being?

Comment: @MarcGravell,Miroslav, Yes you both right but still there are little bit confusion Font.Bold is Property Read Only value and FontStyle.Bold is Enum Items. Why this Bold property and Enum Items are separated?. This Bold create confusion on mind with Enum and Class.

Comment: @mahesh because properties and enum-values are not the same thing. The fact that two types have a member called "Bold" is irrelevant.

Comment: why there is need to check whether font is bold or not you can just imply it on controls whether it is bold or not.

Comment: @MarcGravell, yes both are irrelevant it is true but why there is need to create Bold as a property and enum item. see Font.Bold is boolean type that's means it has to be need to check. my question is why it is need to check where you can just imply it on controls as value such as Bold/Italic/Underline etc.

Comment: @mahesh `System.Drawing.Font` has a much wider usage. It's used for any GDI+ related graphic manipulation, not just for `System.Windows.Forms` controls. It represents a font typeface. Read-only property `Bold` tells you whether that font typeface is Bold or not. I.e. Arial font has many variations - Regular, Bold, Italic, BoldItalic...

Comment: @MiroslavPopovic, That's means it's for just system use not require on System.windows.Forms controls right?.

Comment: @mahesh If you need to get or set `Bold` for the control, you would use control's property.

Comment: @MiroslavPopovic, Sorry but the Bold property of controls is only read only. then is it possible to read or write on control's Bold property?.

Comment: @mahesh Sorry, haven't worked with WinForms recently... To set `Bold` font you need to set the `Font` property, `Font` class constructor has a `FontStyle` parameter: `textBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)`.

Comment: @MiroslavPopovic,Mark, Thank you very much. You both are awesome but this clarification is very much useful for me because I have a question already in my mind about string format and for that this information would be really help me for preparation of next question of string format which will be ask very soon. thanks